# Lagrange interpolation formula in r programming

Tags: r, function, interpolation

how can I write a function that implements Lagrange interpolation formula in r programming.
I was thinking about using 2 loops.
Thanks in advance for help!!

Comment: You can first research the concept of it and try to code it. You can use (https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/lagrangian-polynomial-interpolation-r) as a basis to create it.

Answer (score 3):

The function `lagrange` below is a function factory, it returns an interpolating function. It only needs one `sapply` loop and returns the vectorized version of the function `f` it creates.

```r
lagrange <- function(x0, y0) {
  f <- function (x) {
    sum(y0 * sapply(seq_along(x0), \(j) {
      prod(x - x0[-j])/prod(x0[j] - x0[-j])
    }))
  }
  Vectorize(f, "x")
}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Test 1

Test the function with `f(x) == x^2`.

```r
x <- 1:5
y = (1:5)^2
f <- lagrange(x, y)
f(1:5)
#> [1]  1  4  9 16 25

plot(x, y)
curve(f, from = 1, to = 5, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Test 2

Test the function with the normal density.

```r
u <- seq(-5, 5, by = 2)
v <- dnorm(u)
g <- lagrange(u, v)

u_new <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 101)
m <- min(g(u_new), dnorm(u_new))
M <- 1.5*max(g(u_new), dnorm(u_new))

plot(u, v, ylim = c(m, M))
curve(dnorm, from = -5, to = 5, col = "black", add = TRUE)
curve(g, from = -5, to = 5, col = "red", add = TRUE)
legend("top", legend = c("Normal", "Lagrange"), 
       col = 1:2, lty = "solid", horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>