# Differences between Lagrange interpolation in R with poly.calc and with custom implementation

Tags: r, interpolation

I am trying to fit a Lagrange interpolation polynomial to a set of points:

```r
x0 <- c(576020169, 576020229, 576020296, 576020366)
y0 <- c(4816.391, 4908.896, 5011.254, 5116.875)
```

I am trying two different ways. The first one is through polynom's poly.calc:

```r
library(polynom)
lagrangeInterpolation1 <- as.function(poly.calc(x0, y0))
```

The second one is through some code I found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73994021/lagrange-interpolation-formula-in-r-programming), which uses a function factory:

```r
lagrange <- function(x0, y0) {
    f <- function (x) {
        sum(y0 * sapply(seq_along(x0), function(j) {
            prod(x - x0[-j])/prod(x0[j] - x0[-j])
        }))
    }
    return(Vectorize(f, "x"))
}
lagrangeInterpolation2 <- lagrange(x0, y0)
```

Applying the two yields very different results, with the one obtained through the custom code being the correct one. For example, for a value of x=576020225 (which is in the interpolation interval):

```r
lagrangeInterpolation1(576020225) # 2.486671e+18
lagrangeInterpolation2(576020225) # 4902.472 , reasonable and correct
```

Any idea what could possibly be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that the failing polynomial fitter is a bit simple minded and has built up a naive polynomial fitting matrix with a terrible condition number due to the large DC offset in X values. Any sensible fitting algorithm that was intended to be accurate would rescale the X data range onto -1,1 beforehand (or at the very least subtract the mean value of the Xn).

Subtracting 576020300 from all of your X values and then trying the fit again will probably resolve the problem. It does for Excel (although I confess that I had expected Excel charts to actually get it right!).

Computing (A+x)^N with a large additive constant A can be a disaster.

BTW your set of points looks to be almost exactly linear which isn't a particularly good functional test of Lagrange interpolation.

FWIW I get the linear equation using Excel as

```
y = 1.51927651798024x - 8.7512909703529400E+08
R² = 9.9997709635592700E-01
```

But if I try to fit a quadratic there I get a completely nonsensical "answer" with a plausible but meaningless R² value - I'm a little bit surprised as I thought it was better than that. I had actually expected it to work!

Excel failed quadratic fit using original X values with large offset:

```
y = -1.2529309982056700E-04x2 + 1.4434425517145300E+05x - 4.1573047570104200E+13
R² = 9.9999994440119700E-01
```

Excel successful quadratic fit with modified X' = X-567020300 :

```
y = -1.2529309982056700E-04x2 + 1.5172783075004900E+00x + 5.0172911254711800E+03
R² = 9.9999994440119700E-01
```

It seems to me that the polynom library needs some attention!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Normalizing the input X values to the [-1, 1] interval before interpolation has indeed solved all problems!

Comment: You should probably report it as a fault in polynom to who ever maintains it - no self respecting polynomial fitting package should fall into that particular bear trap.